# How can I test landscape view using the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cordova, ios-simulator

I wonder if I can test landscape view using simulator?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[image]

Under the Hardware Menu you will find the rotation items which correspond to CMD+Left and CMD+Right

Comment: When I do this, the simulator rotates, but the content doesn't adjust for the new orientation. I'm running iOS Simulator 5.0 (272), part of xCode 4.2 Build 4C100 under Snow Leopard, running in a VirtualBox (v.4.1.4r74291) under Windows 7.

Comment: Did you make the changes in the build settings of project under General-> Deployment info-> Device Orientation-> Potrait(uncheck)?

Comment: I was also getting confused with this. 
But then realized if you’re in the home screen of an actual physical iPhone (or Android), the mode is always portrait mode.
Landscape mode only works in the scope of each app.

You can confirm this moving the simulator to landscape mode and opening Safari, for instance. You’ll see now that Safari opens in landscape mode. And when you close it, the home screen goes back to portrait mode.

Answer (score 21):

In the Hardware menu, there is an option to change the orientation. Also, Cmd-Left and Cmd-Right will rotate the virtual phone.

Answer (score 3):

- Setting simulator orientation in IDE

The above (hardware->device) is a solution for rotating the simulator only once the simulator is launched ,but there should be also an option in your IDE to define the orientation of the simulator.

If you are using JDeveloper IDE the go to

**Application --> Deploy --> New Deployment Profile --> select Profile Type(iOS) --> iOS Options --> Device Orientations.**
[IDE Device orientations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPxpk.png)
There you can mention which orientation you need by default, either landscape or portrait.

- Short cut key for switching Orientations

**Press command key and press left arrow / right arrow.**
This would switch between the landscape and portrait views you require.

I hope this might help your query.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was struggling with this exact problem for about an hour.

On the left-most project navigator screen, click the name of your project (should be the highest dropdown button), then click the general tab on the page that opens up, scroll down and you should see a section titled "Deployment Info" Make sure you select the checkbox of each orientation you want available for your project.

Test your simulation again.